# Use * as regular character filtering object with 'LIKE' in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

I try to find string which contains substring with wildcard symbol. At following  example string should confirm pattern 
**(any symbols '*' any symbols 'p' any symbols)** .
I try this code to search objects from Realm

```
class ServiceMessage: Object {
  @objc dynamic var desc = ""
}

let realm = try! Realm()

let dataSource = [
    "Domain CheckService",
    "IMEI check",
    "Compliant about service provider",
    "Compliant about TRA",
    "Enquires",
    "Suggestion",
    "SMS* S[pam",
    "Poor Coverage",
    "Pure *Signal",
    "Help Salim"
]

for text in dataSource {
    let sm = ServiceMessage()
    sm.desc = text;
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(sm)
    }
}


let searchString = "*\\**p*"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.desc LIKE[c] %@", searchString)
let errors = realm.objects(ServiceMessage.self).filter(predicate)
```

I got nothing. 
If i try to filter simple array of strings with this Predicate everything work fine. Does anybody know solutions for this problem? I try add [w] after **LIKE** it's doesn't help me.

Comment: Did my answer help you???

Comment: hi ,thank you for you answer but no. 1. As you can see i mentioned that i can filter array with predicate, at the same, for me your pattern more difficult then i use. Also i don't want use regular expression. As i understand i used reserved wildcard, so i just want use this symbol as symbol and not as reserved character.

Comment: ok, good luck with that, when you find an answer for this please post it

Comment: @ReinierMelian appreciate you help, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you can't use regular expression as predicates in `Realm` as we can read here https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2629 the properly way to do this should be

```
let realmInstance = try? Realm()
let expresion = ".*\\*.*p.*"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name MATCHES %@", expresion)
self.realmArrayDogs = realmInstance?.objects(Dog.self).filter(predicate)
```

**but this will crash with the following error**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid operator type',
>   reason: 'Operator 'MATCHES' not supported for string type'

**this is an example of the same working with an stringArray**

```
let array = ["D*usadpdasd","probando","asdasd*ffffpppp"]
    do{
        let expresion = ".*\\*.*p.*"
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@",expresion)
        let resultArray = array.filter({predicate.evaluate(with: $0)})
        debugPrint(resultArray)
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

As a workaround you can convert the Result from Realm to Array and then filter with predicate

**This works!**

```
let realmInstance = try? Realm()
let expresion = ".*\\*.*p.*"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name MATCHES %@", expresion)
let arrayOfDogsResult = realmInstance?.objects(Dog.self)
let filteredArray = Array(arrayOfDogsResult!).filter({predicate.evaluate(with: $0)})
debugPrint(filteredArray)
```